# Field is not writeable: QuoteDocument.Name

Tags: quote, document

Is there any way to go around this and write the name of the new  QuoteDocument and then Insert it ? One way that I thought about it is to create a new quote just before inserting it, but then the document will be attached to another quote and it would be lost. I thought perhaps there might be setting in salesforce so I can make it writeable .

```
 doc = new QuoteDocument(Document = record.body , QuoteId = urlId );
         System.debug('I got to here for the Name of the Doc' + doc.Name);
         if ( doc.Name == NULL){
          Quote qot = new Quote();
          doc.Name =  Name +'_' + datetime.now();
          qot.Name = Name +'_' + datetime.now();
          System.debug('Qote name' + qot.Name);
         }
        Database.SaveResult insertResult = Database.Insert(doc, false);
        System.debug('record Id' + doc.Id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Name field is managed by the system, much like an autonumber field is. You cannot specify a Name value directly. The autogenerated name will be in the form of "QuoteName_V#.pdf", where QuoteName is the name of the quote, and # will be the next incremented version number for that quote.